# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Network Engineering breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0         12
Users destroyed                                   6          0
Users deleted                                     4          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           779        426
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue              211         75
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        122        114
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              200         78
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue             1,177        924
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              778        138
Tags merged                                       2          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             1          0
Tag synonyms created                              1          0
Revisions redacted                                6          0
Questions reopened                               68          1
Questions protected                              11          6
Questions migrated                                6          0
Questions flagged⁴                                8        310
Questions closed                              2,917          4
Question flags handled⁴                         222         96
Posts unlocked                                    0          1
Posts undeleted                                   5         49
Posts locked                                      0         20
Posts deleted⁵                                  962      2,898
Posts bumped                                      0      2,235
Comments undeleted                                4          0
Comments flagged                                  0        386
Comments deleted⁶                               538        823
Comment flags handled                           107        279
Answers flagged                                   0        329
Answer flags handled                            289         40
All comments on a post moved to chat              3          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...